# Overloading >> operator C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I already posted a question about this but didn't get a helpful answer, I'm very new to C++ and I've been stuck on this problem for over 3 hours and I'm sorry if it's a stupid small thing but I can't work it out.

I'm trying to read information from a text file with the format:

```
1 David Davidson: 64 Zoo Lane
2 Homer Simpson: 123 Fake Street, Springfield
3 Craig Boone: Presidential Suite, Lucky 38, New Vegas
...etc
```

I want to store the information in a class called Borrower with fields for their ID number, name, and address so I've overloaded the >> operator as follows:
(Borrower.cpp)

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Borrower& b) {
    in >> b.idNumber;
    std::getline(in, b.name, ':');
    in.ignore(1);
    in >> b.address;
    return in;
}
```

and I'm implementing it in main.cpp like this:

```
    ifstream fileUsers;
    fileUsers.open("users.txt");
    Borrower b;
    while (fileUsers.good()){
        fileUsers >> b;
        cout << b;
    }
```

I'm getting all sorts of errors and I can't see what i've done wrong:
Please help :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kJoK.png

Edit: Class definition:

```
class Borrower {
public:
    int idNumber;
    string name;
    string address;
    vector<LibraryBook> booksOnLoan;
    vector<LibraryBook> previousLoans;
    Borrower();
    Borrower(int theIdNumber, string theName, string theAddress);
    int getIdNumber();
    string getName();
    string getAddress();
    istream& operator >>(istream& in, Borrower& b);
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Borrower& b);   
};
```

Comment: Please include the relevant `Borrower` class definition.

Comment: How is `main.cpp` aware that `istream& operator>>(istream& in, Borrower& b);` even *exists* ? If all you're including is the header and that free-operator isn't declared in said-same, `main.cpp` is rightly complaining it has no idea what you're trying to call.

Comment: He should have a prototype in the class definition, yes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to `friend` the operator so ifstream can access your object. Haven't done this in a while though, but here's a link to a tutorial about it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm

Edit: sorry then. Also, I'm a bit confused about your use of std::getline() in the middle of your input overload.

Comment: The error says nothing about accessibility issues (yet).

Comment: I've tried it with and without. Also, I've overloaded the ostream operator<< in a similar way and that works fine

Comment: OK well I'm not sure what I did differently that time, but I tried adding friend again and now it works. Sorry

Comment: @MattPashby The reasoning for this answer is wrong, which suggests you don't understand why `friend` "fixed" the problem.

Comment: This "fixed" it (term used loosely) because the friend declaration also provided *a declaration at all*; something that was lacking in the header (and thusly the including main.cpp) to begin with. All the members in this class are public. There are no access issues. Simply declaring `std::istream& operator >>(std::istream&, Borrower&);` *after* the class would have fixed this as well. The point is `main.cpp` had no idea the operator existed, being declared and defined simultaneously (and only) in Borrower.cpp.

Comment: Adding to what @WhozCraig sais, I the main point is that the operator was declared as a member (giving it the wrong signature), and `friend` makes it a non-member. But simply making it a non-member also makes is a non-member :-)

Answer (score 1):

If this operator overload only exists in Borrower.cpp then main will not be able to find it.

Add the prototype of the function to Borrower.h

So in Borrower.h, after the class definition, add the following line:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Borrower& b);
```